# Rearranging order of TableView cells using Core Data

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, core-data

I have a custom UITableView class that handles animations for table view, and have tested the following code with an `Array` that is displayed in a table view.

```
tableView.didMoveCellFromIndexPathToIndexPathBlock = {(fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Void in

  self.objectsArray.exchangeObjectAtIndex(toIndexPath.row, withObjectAtIndex: fromIndexPath.row)

}
```

This works fine with a basic array, but I actually want to rearrange a managed object of a type NSSet. So in my file I have declared the following which creates returns an array of type Item which is used by the table view.

Folder class function:

```
 func itemArray() -> [Item] {
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)
    return iist.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([sortDescriptor]) as! [Item]
}
```

Table View Controller declaration

```
var itemArray = [Item]()
    itemArray = folder.itemArray() //class function to return a NSArray of the NSSET [Item]
```

I am trying to make it so when rearranging the cells it changes the order of the NSSet so it is saved when the app reloads, does anyone have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, NSSets do not have an order so there is no native way for you to preserve the order of the NSSet. I am not saying it is not possible but you cannot do it the way you are thinking.

From [Apple's NSSet Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/index.html):

> The NSSet, NSMutableSet, and NSCountedSet classes declare the programmatic interface to an **unordered** collection of objects.

You will need to convert your NSSet to NSMutableArray and reference that array instead of the NSSet.

Comment: When you say convert my NSSet to a Mutable Array do you mean changing my class function to cast to an NSMutableArray ?

Comment: No, you can't just cast it. You need to change your function to work with a NSMutableArray instead of the NSSet. You would probably initialize this array using something like `yourMutableArray = [mySet allObjects]` then just keep using this array to do your sorting

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am still currently working on your suggestion, unfortunately running into problems, have made a different post if you would like to check it out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31257572/error-could-not-find-overload-for-title-that-accepts-the-supplied-arguments/31257746#31257746