# Error: Could not find overload for 'title' that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nsmutablearray

Currently I have a subclass of NSManaged object called `Folder` with property called `item` that is of type `NSSet`. I have a function to return a `NSMutableArray` and I am trying to display the data in a tableview (and then rearrange the order displayed in the table).

```
class Folder: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var title: String
@NSManaged var date: NSDate
@NSManaged var item: NSSet

func itemMutableArray() -> NSMutableArray {
    return NSMutableArray(array: (item.allObjects as! [Checklist]).sorted{ $0.date.compare($1.date) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending } )
}
```

TableViewController:

```
 var itemMutableArray: NSMutableArray!
 itemMutableArray = folder.itemMutableArray() 

 cell.textLabel?.text = itemMutableArray[indexPath.row].title //Error
```

Unfortunately this returns an error in my tableview when using this function.

> Error could not find overload for 'title' that accepts the supplied arguments

**Ultimately** what I am trying to achieve is to display the data and move the cells around to change the order of the NSSet.

```
 table.didMoveCellFromIndexPathToIndexPathBlock = {(fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Void in

  let delegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
  let context: NSManagedObjectContext = delegate.managedObjectContext!

  context.deleteObject(self.itemArray[indexPath!.row] as NSManagedObject )  

  self.itemArray.exchangeObjectAtIndex(toIndexPath.row, withObjectAtIndex: fromIndexPath.row)

 }
```

PS: Originally I had a function to return an array of the object but I was unable to modify the order of the NSSet as they are not ordered.

```
func itemArray() -> [Item] {
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)
    return item.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([sortDescriptor]) as! [Item]
}
```

Does anybody have any suggestions with where I am currently going wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the expression `itemMutableArray[indexPath.row].title` is that, because you have typed `itemMutableArray` as an NSMutableArray, `itemMutableArray[indexPath.row]` is an AnyObject. Thus, Swift has no reason to believe that this thing has a `title` property. You need to cast it to something that *does* have a `title` property (though it would be much better to avoid the use of NSMutableArray completely, if possible, since a Swift array *is* mutable).

Comment: So are you suggesting change the function in my subclass to return a swift array then use a swift array in my table view controller ? I am a little confused atm as I have been receiving different advice on how to achieve the ability to modify the order of the tableview. I originally had a different function that created an swift array of type [Item] but this was not mutable.

Comment: A Swift array of type `[item]`, declared with `var`, _is_ mutable. However, do what you want to do. I'm just saying that _if_ you insist on using NSMutableArray, _then_ Swift has no type info on the elements of the array and that is why you are getting the error. And I told you how to solve it. What road you go down is up to you.

Comment: I mean I could not exchange the index path of type NSSet because it has no order. I am unsure how to move table view cells with core data but I understand your answer answers my question and why I receive the error therefor will accept your answer.

Comment: " I am unsure how to move table view cells with core data" I don't know what you mean by the words "move table view cells". But if that's what you really want to know, you should ask _that_ as a new question!

Comment: Also, if order and indexability by integer is important to you — e.g., the fourth row of the table is to be populated from the fourth item in this collection — then choosing a set as a collection type would be very silly. An array is a natural basis for a table view's data model.

Comment: I am new to iOS development,when working with core data and setting a relationship to 'to many' then I have to work with the NSSet type. I can then only create an array of the type NSSet or am I missing something ?

Comment: That is what we agreed you should be asking a new question about, is it not?

Comment: Sorry, but something just occurred to me. If you are truly new to iOS development, does this mean you are also new to Core Data? Because Core Data is _not_ a beginner technology; you shouldn't be using it unless you have to. (Of course, you may have to. You may be a big Core Data expert from over on the Mac side of things.)